# Clear ThreadLocal value while returning to ThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

While reusing Thread from thread pool, we get thread local variable value from the last execution of the thread.

I understand that Thread local is part of Thread so it is getting reused when we use Thread pool. But my problem is I do not want to use thread local variable set in the last execution (valid use case for many people).

Is there any better way of clearing thread local values when thread goes to the pool after current execution?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Why don't you simply reset your thread pool variable when requesting a thread instance from the pool?

Comment: Not clearing `ThreadLocal` values is one of the classic examples of memory leaks in Java. I would suggest that you wrap your operation in some sort of interceptor pattern and clear the value when you're done with it. Are you using an `ExectuorService`?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to clear ThreadLocals using public API. Nevertheless, ThreadPoolExecutor has  a hook method where we can clear ThreadLocals in Thread using reflection before execution

```
public class ThreadPoolExector
    protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
         ... set t.threadLocals and t.inheritableThreadLocals fields to null using reflection
    }
    ...

public class Thread
    ...
    ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap threadLocals;
    ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap inheritableThreadLocals;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the thread local map for a thread using reflection.  This will clear all thread locals no matter where they are.

Ideally, you should write your code so your thread locals are not stateful like this.  This means unit testing much harder.

Answer (score 1):

It should be the responsibility of the "thread user" to clear the ThreadLocal - that is, the code that put the ThreadLocal in place shall also clear it. Use e.g. a try-finally-block to make sure this happens.

However, you can hack what you want! Seriously, it is not difficult - you just introspect your way into the Thread object/class, find the Map where the ThreadLocals reside, and clear it.